# Kentico - failure to validate security headers

Tags: kentico

As per the https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-10068

> An issue was discovered in Kentico before 12.0.15. Due to a failure to
>   validate security headers, it was possible for a specially crafted
>   request to the staging service to bypass the initial authentication
>   and proceed to deserialize user-controlled .NET object input. This
>   deserialization then led to unauthenticated remote code execution on
>   the server where the Kentico instance was hosted.

Does this apply to v12 only or lower versions are affected by it as well like v8.2 and v9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will need workaround for older versions or prior to v12.0.5

Take a look under security bugs
https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes#securityBugs-v12

> Due to an error in the Microsoft.Web.Services3 library, it was
>   possible for a specially crafted request on staging service to bypass
>   the initial authentication and proceed to deserialize user-controlled
>   input. The deserialization of the user-controlled input then led to
>   remote code execution on the server where the Kentico instance was
>   hosted.
>
> Workaround for all Kentico versions The workaround for this issue is
>   the same for all projects, regardless of staging utilization - set the
>
> 'Staging service authentication' setting to 'X.509':
>
> 1. Navigate to 'Settings' -> 'Versioning & Synchronization' -> 'Staging'
>
> 2. Under the 'Staging service' section set 'Staging service authentication' to 'X.509'
>
> 3. 'Save' the changes
>
> Details
>
> Issue type: Remote Code Execution Security risk:
>
> Critical Found in version:
>
> 12.0.14 and below Fixed in version:
>
> 12.0.15 Fixed date: 3/22/2019 Reported by: Aon’s Cyber Solutions Recommendation
>
> Install the latest hotfix. You can download the latest
>
> hotfix from Download section on the DevNet portal. If you use an older
>
> Kentico version, it is highly recommended to upgrade to the latest